# android how to make transpernt child layout parent background having some color

Tags: android, layout

I am trying to make below layout. The problem is to set camera and its below portion transparent. I have rounded image of camera but how to put in layout so that I can get below layout.

I have tried the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:background="@drawable/bg_app">

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/font_xtr_large"

        android:gravity="center"

        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivlogo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_medium"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_login_logo" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ivlogo"
            android:background="@color/color_white"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"


                android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/Camera" />
        </LinearLayout>





    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
Misunderstand your question first time. So you can try to create picture with empty half-circle with specific radius, then create circle button with this radius-padding and put it there.

So here is simple layout just to make you understand the idea

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#15aa12"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="#fff" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#5476aa">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#fff">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:text="test" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:text="test" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:text="test" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

So you need to create picture like this (transparent at the top pard and without camera circle button. Then put this picture as background of middle layout and set button proper form[image]

[image: test]

Here is picture of xml file I created

Comment: but here how can i set transparency ? if i set transparency entire white then and then camera image background show transparent but i also not do entire background transpernt i  need white color too

Comment: I will build xml file wait a sec

Answer (score 0):

Try with following steps:

1. Set grapes image as background of your layout.
2. You have to create one image with round in the center and has white background color in bottom half and transparent color to upper half.
3. Use this image as parent background of your Camera button.
4. Set your camera button to center of the parent.
5. The bottom half, after the camera parent, set its background color to white.